# Regarding Laplace transformation and convolution integral

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

I have a problem concerning Laplace transform and convolution integral as attached:

[Problem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9L7l.png)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you define

$$
\mathcal{F}(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}t~e^{-st}f(t)
$$

then

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}t~e^{-st/\tau}f(t) = \mathcal{F}(s/\tau) \not= \mathcal{F}(s)
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have modified the problem statement for further clarity.